# RuntimeException - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android

I've just downloaded [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) app, to investigate how it handles switching between phone and tablet layouts:

I used EGit and there was an error:
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.6'

I fixed it easely thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013445/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-4) question and Ted Hopp's answer.

Now the project compiled, but right at the start it crashes:

> 07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.google.android.apps.iosched.provider.ScheduleProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.apps.iosched.provider.ScheduleProvider in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.google.android.apps.iosched-1.apk]
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3865)
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3617)
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3573)
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123) 07-11
>   02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1031)
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-11
>   02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126) 07-11 02:23:37.266:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997) 07-11
>   02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-11
>   02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 07-11 02:23:37.266:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 07-11
>   02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-11 02:23:37.266:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1881): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.apps.iosched.provider.ScheduleProvider in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.google.android.apps.iosched-1.apk]
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548) 07-11
>   02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508) 07-11
>   02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3850)
>   07-11 02:23:37.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):   ... 12 more

I can see that there this class **com.google.android.apps.iosched.provider.ScheduleProvider** in the project. Can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by "I used EGit and there" you most probably used eclipse. I am afraid that the project is created in/for Android Studio and it will be very painful to try to setup it in eclipse - I wasted several hours trying with no luck... ...at the end I gived up and installed the Android Studio. There are more than 20 additional libraries that need to be added to the project in order to be able to run.
I have several free hours so I will give a try to the Android Studio but probably the google guys had to warn us on the project page that the project wont run in eclipse...
(of course there is a BUILDING.txt in the project root)